# How to fill List to be size 3 but don't overwrite existing values

Tags: java

I need to make sure that a List has exactly 3 items. Input examples:

```
1. ["item", "item", "item"]
2. ["item", "item"]
3. []
```

Target output examples:

```
1. ["item", "item", "item"]
2. ["item", "item", "fallback"]
3. ["fallback", "fallback", "fallback"]
```

I tried to use `Collections.fill(items, "fallback");` but this overwrites the `"item"` values which I need to retain.

Comment: So you want to add items only to the *end* of the list?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, just fill it up to make sure that `size()` will be `3`

Comment: Then write your own fill() method. If the list length is less than 3 then you know how many fallback items you have to add. Then add these fallback items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `fill`, use `addAll` and `nCopies`:

```
if (items.size() < 3) {
  items.addAll(Collections.nCopies(3 - items.size(), "fallback"));
}
```

As it says [in the Javadoc of `nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-):

> This method is useful in combination with the List.addAll method to grow lists.

Answer (score 1):

While you could combine together some provided functionality to achieve it, writing your own `fill` method seems the most straightforward to me:

```
private static void fill(List<String> list, String fallback) {
  if (list.size() > 3) {
    //do something?
  }
  while (list.size() < 3) {
    list.add(fallback);
  }
}
```

Example:

```
public class RandomStuff {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("item", "item", "item"));
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("item", "item"));
    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list4 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("item", "item", "item", "item"));
    String fallback = "fallback";
    fill(list1, fallback);
    fill(list2, fallback);
    fill(list3, fallback);
    fill(list4, fallback);
    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println(list2);
    System.out.println(list3);
    System.out.println(list4);
  }

  private static void fill(List<String> list, String fallback) {
    //body above
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate on the differences to `.addAll(Collections.nCopies(...));`. Is it a performance thing?

Comment: @sandrooco Even if there is difference in performance, it's negligible. I believe this approach is more straightforward and easier to understand what's happening when reading the code.